# Dual boot setup- no GRUB on boot

Tags: dual-boot, bios, grub-efi

On a dual boot Ubuntu 18.04LTS -Windows 10 setup.

By default I launch into Ubuntu

I see a black screen on boot for about 10 seconds then my desktop.

I last reconfigured my setup over a year ago but can't recall what I did to hide the GRUB on boot.
I was able to see the GRUB menu on boot at one time.

My goal is simply to log into BIOS to switch my startup to my Windows partition.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: With UEFI, you should be able to press escape after UEFI boot screen & before grub. But if UEFI fast boot on, you may not have time. You also should be able to press key to get into UEFI boot menu often f10 or f12 but varies. If you set grub timeout to 0 it can be a problem.

Comment: You are not clear in what you want. Do you want to boot to grub, ie get grub screen back, or boot directly to Windows without grub? You should not need to keep using BIOS to decide where to boot to. That's what grub is for.

Comment: You said that **your goal is simply to log into BIOS to switch my startup to my Windows partition**. Reboot the system. Press `del` key and reach BIOS setup screen. Set up `Windows loader` to top priority  among bootloaders present  there. Done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change some grub options by editing the `/etc/default/grub` file. One thing to try could be to change the GRUB_TIMEOUT value there to some larger value, like 30 or so, then it should wait for 30 seconds hopefully giving your screen enough time to show the menu.

After editing the `/etc/default/grub` file, run the update-grub command:

```
update-grub
```

and then reboot.

Answer (score -1):

When you boot up your computer, after the BIOS splash screen, you should start spamming <kbd>Shift</kbd>